# Backbone.js route optional parameter

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, routes

Is it possible to have optional parameters in a Backbone.js route?

e.g this:

```
routes:
  "search/[:query]": "searchIndex"
```

instead of:

```
routes:
  "search/": "searchIndex"
  "search/:query": "searchIndex"
```

Comment: Gabe H's answer should be the accepted answer, rather than @mu is too short.

Comment: Yes! Techmology advanced!

Comment: Routes like "search/:query" is not working for me. However "search" is working fine. Any idea?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

As of Backbone 0.9.9, you can add optional paramaters with parentheses.

For example in your routes object you can define an optional route part like this:

```
routes: {
    "organize(/:action)": "displayOrganize"
}
```

Now the url path will match `/#organize` and routes like `/#organize/create`.

Keep in mind that if you need routes like `/#organize/` (with a trailing slash) to be recognized, you can do:

```
routes: {
    "organize(/)(:action)": "displayOrganize"
}
```

Comment: How do you handle action within displayOrganize?  i.e.  can you do `displayOrganize: function(action){ if(action){ // do stuff... }}` ?

Comment: url = url + '(/)'; // backbonejs optional handling of trailing slash

Answer (score 16):

Probably the most easiest way is just declare more than one route, one with the extra arg,one without:

```
routes:{
        "authProxy/:hash": "authProxy",                                                                                                                                                                 
        "authProxy/:hash/:url": "authProxy"
}
```

then just check for them in your method:

```
authProxy: function(hash, url){
    if (url){
      // Hash and URL.
    }else{
      // Just hash.
    }
}
```

Note that I like this much better than the other two answers because it's very easy for another developer to understand what's going on.

Answer (score 8):

You can add regex based routes manually using [the `route` method](http://backbonejs.org/#Router-route):

> **route** `router.route(route, name, [callback])`
>
> Manually create a route for the router, The `route` argument may be a routing string or regular expression. Each matching capture from the route or regular expression will be passed as an argument to the callback.

So something like this should work:

```
this.route(/^search\/(.*)?/, 'searchIndex');
```

Then `searchIndex` would get called with your nothing or your `:query` as its argument.

The downside is that you can't put regex routes into your `routes` object. You could add all your routes with `route` inside your router's `initialize` method if you wanted to keep them all together.

Answer (score 3):

What about using the `*splat`:

> **routes** `router.routes`
>
> The routes hash maps URLs with parameters to functions on your router, similar to the View's events hash. Routes can contain parameter parts, `:param`, which match a single URL component between slashes; and splat parts `*splat`, which can match any number of URL components.
>
> For example, a route of `"search/:query/p:page"` will match a fragment of `#search/obama/p2`, passing `"obama"` and `"2"` to the action. A route of `"file/*path"` will match `#file/nested/folder/file.txt`, passing `"nested/folder/file.txt"` to the action.