# Backbone.js: trailing slash in the end of url route

Tags: javascript, url, backbone.js, router

I have url routes in my app `Router.js`:

```
'items': 'items',
'items/drafts': 'itemsDrafts',
'items/drafts/new': 'itemsDraftsNew',
...
```

But in browser when I define `items/drafts/new/` it gives me 404 error :(

Is there a way to make this urls the same without copy-pasting all routes and adding trailing to them like:

```
'items': 'items',
'items/drafts': 'itemsDrafts',
'items/drafts/new': 'itemsDraftsNew',
'items/': 'items',
'items/drafts/': 'itemsDrafts',
'items/drafts/new/': 'itemsDraftsNew',
...
```

?

Thanks!

Answer (score 44, accepted):

my solution: `'url(/)': 'urlFunc'`

`()` - means optional (also take a look here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/14329976/2117550)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to provide the answer of your own question, this is very considerate of the fellow developers of the internet.

Comment: Anyone knows if there's a way to make it default? Instead of adding (/) to every possible route

Comment: url = url + '(/)'; // backbonejs optional handling of trailing slash