# Backbone routes, the application starts inside /profile?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, url-routing

So I don't use any backbone logic until the user logs into the app. So for using node.js the application starts on `localhost:3000` and the server handles the routes in this portion. So for example after visiting `localhost:3000` there are two options, **signup**, or **login** which express handles the engineering of this, and a simple routes.js file handles the logic for these routes.  `/signup`, `/login`

That part is all server side, no need for backbone.js at this point in my opinion.

Then finally the user successfully logs into the app, which starts in `/profile` that is where I include backbone and my javascripts, here is where I rely more on client side routing and logic because the user is approved to play, and is granted access.

Now being kind of noobish here, but my question is since my app starts inside `/profile` why does the router get jacked up? For example I have a `chat` route and to invoke this route the url doesn't respect a trailing slash `localhost:3000/profile#chat` works but not this `localhost:3000/profile/#chat`

I read this [Backbone.js route optional parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9600390/backbone-js-route-optional-parameter/14329976#14329976) I tried  reversing the syntax but no luck.

Here are my routes

```
module.exports = Router = Marionette.AppRouter.extend({
    appRoutes: {
        ''  : 'home',
        '(/:)chat' : 'chat' // tried playing around here
    }
});
```

So since starting on the `/profile` route created by the server how do I get a trailing slash to work?

Answer (score 0):

Backbone is a frontend JS framework completely separate from your node/express backend. They don't share any logic as far as routing is concerned.

Use express to serve the /profile route:

```
app.get('/profile', function(req, res){
  res.render('profile', {somedata:'somevalue'}); // etc..
});
```

Then on the fronend, your Backbone.Router handles any routes from there on:

```
var myRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: {
    '/' : 'profile', // Actually '/profile/
    '/chat' : 'chat' // Actually '/profile/chat
  }
});
```

Lastly, remember to call `Backbone.history.start()` after your router and all routes have been defined to start monitoring for hash changes.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate it, the example above looks like it should work. I get that defining the home/profile route with a '/' should be the answer, but it's not working for some reason.

Comment: I think it may be because the script is not getting included.. Hold on let me do some debugging. I feel like this should work.

Comment: Yeah it seems like on that route I am getting 404 errors for my scripts and css. Express has to be confusing my application.

Comment: My script is in `js/myapp.js` http is requesting `/profile/js/myapp.js`

Comment: Okay so I got it to work, but not with the trailing slash on the chat route. When I add `'/chat': 'chat'` this tells express or node or whatever to get my files at `profile/js/myapp.js`.. When `'chat': 'chat'` allows this `/profile#chat` and gets my files appropriately.